# Pause c program with input redirection

Tags: c

I wrote the following simple code in c and used input redirection with a batch file. How can I pause the program inside the while loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
  char buffer[2048];

    while ( !feof(stdin) ) {
    gets( buffer );
    printf( "%s", buffer );
    //I want to pause the program here, until i press enter
    }
  return 0;
}
```

The batch file is:
main.exe < input.txt >output.txt

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What? You're getting input from input.txt but the file itself is reading from text.txt? You need some sort of delimiter in input.txt that's equivalent to enter, because you're not reading from stdin.

Comment: what do you mean by "pause" and what problem are searching to resolve?

Comment: sorry my fault. i'll correct it!

Comment: the program ends when feof (stdin) == 1 and not when i press Ctrl-Z.
Also, i can't pause it somehow, because getchar() takes input from input.txt

Comment: What on Earth are you trying to do‽ Either the program reads standard input, but than it should just process them and finish and not need any user interaction, or it needs user interaction, but than it should probably read the data from somewhere else and use stdin, stdout and stderr for interacting with the user.

Comment: Note that to make sure you see any errors when running the program from terminal window that will automatically close (like when batch is run on windows, but you didn't say whether that's your case), you can add the pause _after_ your program into the script that starts it.

Comment: I'm trying to pause the program inside the loop (where the comment is).. Looking for a function that doesn't take the redirected input.. Does anything like that exist? Yes i added pause after the program, but that's not the problem, it just doesn't allow the window to close..

Comment: On a side note: **Forget that `gets` ever existed!** It is the most dangerous function in C standard library. Because you can never guarantee that the input line won't be longer than the buffer you allocated. And when it does, crash is the best thing that can happen.

Comment: But _why_ are you trying to pause the program? The input is there, the program does not need to wait for anything.

Comment: my real program is very big and i wrote this small just to express the question.. I need to pause it, just to read the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void){
    char buffer[2048];

    while ( !feof(stdin) ) {
        gets( buffer );
        printf("%s", buffer );
        while(!_kbhit());
        _putch('\n');
        while(_kbhit())
            _getch();
    }
    return 0;
}
```